# Boolean masking of arrays in 3D surface plot destroys colormap

Tags: python, matplotlib

I try to 3D-plot function `fun` and use colormap to show the level of function values. I'd like to plot this function on a non-sqaured area and hence I used boolean mask to set `np.nan` to certain values in meshgrid. But I got

```
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in less
  cbook._putmask(xa, xa < 0.0, -1)
```

whenever I added boolean mask. It seems the bug is due to that `np.nan` cannot be compared in colormap. But I can't find a way to fix this.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
import numpy as np

%matplotlib inline

fun = lambda x: np.sin(x[0])*np.exp(1-np.cos(x[1]))**2 + np.cos(x[1])*np.exp(1-np.sin(x[0]))**2 + (x[0]-x[1])**2

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 5))
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
x = np.arange(-6, 6, 3e-2)
y = np.arange(-6, 6, 3e-2)

# A constraint on x and y
x, y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
r2 = (x+5)**2 + (y+5)**2
scope = r2 < 25
# Mask is the cause of the problem
x[scope] = np.nan
y[scope] = np.nan
z = fun(np.array([x, y]))

surf=ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, cmap=cm.jet)
ax.contourf(x, y, z, offset=-120, cmap=cm.jet)
fig.colorbar(surf)
ax.view_init(elev=30, azim=60)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot fix the runtime warning. It's a warning based on the fact that there are nan values in the array.

In order to still get a colorcoded surface plot, you can however use a `matplotlib.colors.Normalize` instance to tell the surface plot which colors to use.

See full code below:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.colors

fun = lambda x: np.sin(x[0])*np.exp(1-np.cos(x[1]))**2 + np.cos(x[1])*np.exp(1-np.sin(x[0]))**2 + (x[0]-x[1])**2

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 5))
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
x = np.arange(-6, 6, 3e-2)
y = np.arange(-6, 6, 3e-2)

# A constraint on x and y
x, y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
r2 = (x+5)**2 + (y+5)**2
scope = r2 < 25
# Mask is the cause of the problem
x[scope] = np.nan
y[scope] = np.nan
z = fun(np.array([x, y]))

norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=-120, vmax=120)
cm.jet.set_under((0,0,0,0))
ax.contourf(x, y, z, offset=-120, cmap=cm.jet, norm=norm)
surf=ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, cmap=cm.jet, norm=norm)
fig.colorbar(surf)
#ax.view_init(elev=30, azim=60)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Appreciated. Just wonder how did you choose the value -120 and 120? Also, it looks like the cutting boundary are colored with deep blue? Is this my illusion?

Comment: I chose 120 because this seems to be the range where the data lives. Since I don't know their meaning, It's you who needs to decide the bounds. The edges are indeed deep blue. This is because in those cells matplotlib has to interpolate between nan and a number, which results in nan (=minimum of colormap) but it still shows the cell. You can make that region transparent; i'll edit the answer accordingly.